# If I know $E[\xi]=1$, what can I say about $E[\log (\xi)]$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value

If I know $E[\xi_{i}]=1$, what can I say about $E[\log (\xi_{i})]$?

Background: Let $(\xi_{i})_{i}$ be IID random variables with $E[\xi_{i}]=1$ where $P(\xi_{i}=1)<1$. I want to use the law of large numbers to show that $\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\log (\xi_{i})}{n}\to c < 0$

So I need to show that $E(\log(\xi_{i}))<0$. But all we know about the distribution of $\xi_{i}$ is that $P(\xi_{i}=1)<1$

Note: I previously proved that $X_{n}:=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}\xi_{i}\xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0-$a.s, I do not know whether this helps.

Intuitively it makes sense because comparing the $\xi_{i}>1$ weight with that of $\xi_{i}<1$, moving along the $\log$ curve gives a steeper "decline" than an "increase"

Comment: Keyword: Jensen inequality.

Comment: Maybe the [Law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) can help.

Comment: Adding details to zhoraster's comment, the following version of [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) will help: If $X$ is a random variable taking values in an interval $I$ and $\varphi:I\to\mathbb{R}$ is convex, then $$\varphi(\mathbb{E}[X])\leq\mathbb{E}[\varphi(X)]$$ as long as both sides are well-defined. Moreover, if $\varphi$ is strictly convex, then the equality holds if and only if $X$ is $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You claim, that you have already proved, that $P(\Pi_{i=1}^\infty \xi_i = 0) = 1$. Thus, if you are right, then $$P(\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N} \text{ } \forall n > n_0 \text{ } \Pi_{i=1}^n \xi_i < 1) = 1$$ That means, that $$P(\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N} \text{ } \forall n > n_0 \text{ } \Sigma_{i=1}^n \log(\xi_i) < 0) = 1$$ This results in $$P(\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N} \text{ } \forall n > n_0 \text{ } \frac{1}{n}\Sigma_{i=1}^n \log(\xi_i) < 0) = 1$$ And from that it follows, according to the Law of Large Numbers, that $E[\log(\xi_i)] < 0$, which seems to be the exact thing you wanted to prove.